# Good practice with \DeclareKeys

Tags: theorems, thmtools, key-value, l3keys, thmbox

I'm trying to make a "one-off" theorem environment for theorems with custom names that shouldn't be numbered at all. The goal is to copy the behavior of `thmtools`

```
\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}
```

by directly using the `thmbox` environment and implementing the `label` and `name` options of thmtools, with an unknown key being interpreted as the value to the `name` key. Since the theorem is unnumbered, `\ref` should give the theorem name. There's not much to go on in `clsguide` and my goal was to do this without using the "programming" interface to keyvals (`\keys_define:nn`, etc.). Here's my attempt, which seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,thmtools}

\makeatletter

\newif\if@hasname@

\DeclareKeys[oneoffthm]{
    label .store = \oneoffthm@label,
    storename .store = \oneoffthm@name,
    hasname .if = @hasname@,
    name .meta:n = {hasname,storename=#1},
    }
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[oneoffthm]{\SetKeys[oneoffthm]{name=#1}}
    
\NewDocumentEnvironment{oneoffthm}{m o}{%
    \vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}%
    \begin{thmbox}[M]{%
    \bfseries%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}{%
        \SetKeys[oneoffthm]{#2}%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \label{\oneoffthm@label}%
        \if@hasname@\;(\textit{\oneoffthm@name})\fi%
        }%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \ignorespaces%
    }
    {\end{thmbox}\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}}
    
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\thmboxoptions{bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[1][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name A}
\kant[2][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[a heading]
\kant[3][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name B}[a heading]
\kant[4][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[label=abc]
\kant[5][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name C}[label=customC]
\kant[6][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[name=a heading,label=def]
\kant[7][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name D}[name=a heading,label=customD]
\kant[8][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\ref{abc}

\ref{customC}

\ref{def}

\ref{customD}

\end{document}
```

[image: doc]

My `\DeclareKeys` seems suboptimal. Is there a way to access the key parameters without storing them in macros? This seems like it could be bad in some settings for expansion reasons. Also, is there a way to implement the `name` key without needing to set two other keys? Of course one could say

```
name .code = \@hasname@true\def\oneoffthm@name{#1}
```

but that doesn't seem in the spirit of keyvals.

Unfortunately I cannot adapt [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28319/208544) because thmbox does not allow unnumbered theorems.

**P.S.** The manual vertical spacing in `oneoffthm` is bad, but I don't know of a better option. The default spacing for the plain `thmbox` environment seems incorrect, but the spacing from theorems declared with thmbox is fine, using thmtools or the thmbox package directly. *Edit:* To mimic the behavior of a thmbox-declared theorem, replace the beginning and ending `\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}` with `\medbreak` and `\smallbreak\@endpetrue`, respectively.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow: keys are properties, so there is _always_ a name. Perhaps you want to test whether the name is empty at point-of-use?

Comment: If your names should be printed you can't use `l3keys` for this, as soon as you hit an unknown key the key name got detokenized and isn't valid for printing anymore, just for internal processing. You could however use `expkv` with `expkv-def` (`expkv` allows accessing the key names of undefined keys before they were detokenized).

Comment: And for keys that aren't stored in macros but available as parameters, take a look at `expkv-cs`.

Comment: @JosephWright Really I just wanted to know the "recommended" way to do what I'm doing, since needing two private keys for one public key seems inefficient. But yes, testing for emptiness at point of use is the idea (if I understand correctly)

Comment: why do you need the internal storename and \if@hasname@
 boolean? you could simply intitalise name to something say `\relax` and then if it is not `\relax` a name has been passed in.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought about that. Are you suggesting `name .store = \oneoffthm@name` and then in the definition `\ifx\oneoffthm@name\relax\else\;(\textit{\oneoffthm@name})\fi` ? *edit* That doesn't seem to work but I probably messed something up

Comment: yes with of course `\let\oneoffthm@name\relax` before processing the keys.

Comment: Instead of testing for `\relax` you could as well test against `\@empty` (the difference would be that `name={}` would be considered a name with the `\relax`-test)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, that works. I was trying with `name .initial:n = \relax` which doesn't work

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks! Then there's no need for "initializing" with `.initial:n` or `\let`. I am still curious why the `initial:n = \relax` doesn't work, though

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: @mbert  `initial:n = \relax`  is `\def\oneoffthm@name{\relax}` not `\let` so your `ifx` test would need altering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than treat `[a heading]` as an unknown key you can use the `=` modifier to say an argument that is not a key=value list should be treated as the argument of the `name` key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,thmtools}

\makeatletter

\newif\if@hasname@

\DeclareKeys[oneoffthm]{
    label .store = \oneoffthm@label,
    storename .store = \oneoffthm@name,
    hasname .if = @hasname@,
    name .meta:n = {hasname,storename=#1},
    }

    
\NewDocumentEnvironment{oneoffthm}{m ={name} o}{%
    \vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}%
    \begin{thmbox}[M]{%
    \bfseries%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}{%
        \SetKeys[oneoffthm]{#2}%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \label{\oneoffthm@label}%
        \if@hasname@\;(\textit{\oneoffthm@name})\fi%
        }%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \ignorespaces%
    }
    {\end{thmbox}\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}}
    
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\thmboxoptions{bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[1][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name A}
\kant[2][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[a heading]
\kant[3][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name B}[a heading]
\kant[4][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[label=abc]
\kant[5][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name C}[label=customC]
\kant[6][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[name=a heading,label=def]
\kant[7][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name D}[name=a heading,label=customD]
\kant[8][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\ref{abc}

\ref{customC}

\ref{def}

\ref{customD}

\end{document}
```

You can simplify the key structure, removing meta key and internal boolean:

```
\makeatletter

\DeclareKeys[oneoffthm]{
    label .store = \oneoffthm@label,
    name .store = \oneoffthm@name,
    }

    
\NewDocumentEnvironment{oneoffthm}{m ={name} o}{%
    \vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}%
    \begin{thmbox}[M]{%
    \bfseries%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}{%
        \let\oneoffthm@name\relax
        \SetKeys[oneoffthm]{#2}%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \label{\oneoffthm@label}%
        \ifx\oneoffthm@name\relax\else\;(\textit{\oneoffthm@name})\fi
        }%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \ignorespaces%
    }
    {\end{thmbox}\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}}
    
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `expkv-cs` we can

1. access the unknown key name without detokenizing it
2. access the values of different keys without any expansion problems

The following uses an internal key to pass the key value of `name` with formatting instructions to the underlying macro (this way we don't need a conditional to check whether it was used or not, it'll just be empty if it wasn't used).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,thmtools}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter

\ekvcSplit\oneoffthm@KV
  {
     label         = {}
    ,name-internal = {}
  }
  {\label{#1}#2}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\oneoffthm@KV{meta name = name-internal={\;(\textit{#1})}}
\ekvdefunknownNoVal{\string\oneoffthm@KV}{\ekvmorekv{name={#2}}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{oneoffthm}{m o}{%
    \vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}%
    \begin{thmbox}[M]{%
    \bfseries%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}
      {%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \oneoffthm@KV{#2}%
      }%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \ignorespaces%
    }
    {\end{thmbox}\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\thmboxoptions{bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[1][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name A}
\kant[2][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[a heading]
\kant[3][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name B}[a heading]
\kant[4][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[label=abc]
\kant[5][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name C}[label=customC]
\kant[6][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[name=a heading,label=def]
\kant[7][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name D}[name=a heading,label=customD]
\kant[8][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\ref{abc}

\ref{customC}

\ref{def}

\ref{customD}

\end{document}
```

---

A variant using `expkv-def` instead of `expkv-cs`. With this we can still access the unknown key name without detokenizing it, but also have access to a more traditional key=value approach with defining macros to store key values.

Moreover the `dataT` key-type of `expkv-def` seems very handy for the task at hand (only setting a `\label` if the `label` key was used, only formatting the name if the `name` key was used). A `dataT` key will gobble the token or group following the macro in which it is stored if the key wasn't used (so behave like `\@gobble`), but if it was used it'll expand to the token or group followed by the value in braces (so no expansion problems here as well, the `\label` and `\oneoffthm@name@format` both get the value and not a macro storing it).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,thmtools}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter

\ekvdefinekeys{oneoffthm}
  {
     dataT   label = \oneoffthm@label
    ,dataT   name  = \oneoffthm@name 
    ,unknown noval = \ekvmorekv{name={#2}}
  }
\newcommand\oneoffthm@name@format[1]{\;(\textit{#1})}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{oneoffthm}{m o}{%
    \vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}%
    \begin{thmbox}[M]{%
    \bfseries%
    #1%
    \IfValueT{#2}
      {%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \ekvset{oneoffthm}{#2}%
        \oneoffthm@label\label
        \oneoffthm@name\oneoffthm@name@format
      }%
    }%
    \noindent%
    \ignorespaces%
    }
    {\end{thmbox}\vspace*{0.4\baselineskip}}

\makeatother

\declaretheorem[thmbox=M]{theorem}

\thmboxoptions{bodystyle=\normalfont\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\kant[1][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name A}
\kant[2][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[a heading]
\kant[3][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name B}[a heading]
\kant[4][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[label=abc]
\kant[5][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name C}[label=customC]
\kant[6][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\begin{theorem}[name=a heading,label=def]
\kant[7][1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneoffthm}{Custom Name D}[name=a heading,label=customD]
\kant[8][1]
\end{oneoffthm}

\ref{abc}

\ref{customC}

\ref{def}

\ref{customD}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this answer behaves slightly different from @DavidCarlisle's. Here `[a heading,label=def]` would be valid input being functionally identical to `[name=a heading,label=def]`. In David's answer this would throw an error, and only `[a heading]` is identical to `[name=a heading]`. Which is to be preferred is up to the one defining the interface/the user.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the `expkv` documentation. Lots of nice functionality. Just for the record, the `thmtools` behavior is to not allow `[a heading, label=bla]`

Comment: @mbert well, I didn't take a look at `thmtools` and didn't test it, so how should I know? :P That wouldn't be supported by `expkv` out of the box and rely on external solutions then (like the `={<key>}` processor of `ltcmd` as shown by David).

Comment: My comment was not at all a criticism, just "for the record" in case someone looks at this in the future

Comment: @mbert don't worry, I didn't take it as criticism!